# Sorting a dataset with a group by statement

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am writing a query into a database that tracks the results of athletic competitions.  My database has an athletes table:

```
| id    | first_name    | last_name    | Gender  |
| 1     | Sam           | Johnson      | m       |
| 2     | Adam          | Jones        | m       |
```

and a results table

```
| id    | time          | athlete_id   
| 1     | 1302          | 1            
| 2     | 1420          | 1            
| 3     | 1491          | 2
| 4     | 1541          | 2
| 5     | 0             | 1
```

I want to retrieve all the athletes and only their fastest result. I have a query like this

```
 select a.id as aid, a.`first`, a.`last`, r.`id` as `rid`, min(r.`time`) as `time`
 FROM athletes a, results r 
 WHERE 
   r.athlete_id=a.id AND
   r.time > 0
 GROUP BY a.id
 ORDER BY r.time
```

So far my query does limit the result to the fastest time, but it's not sorting by the time correctly.   I also tried adding second reference to the results table

```
 select a.id as aid, a.`first`, a.`last`, r.`id` as `rid`, r.`time`
 FROM athletes a, results r, results r2
 WHERE 
   r.athlete_id=a.id AND
   r2.athlete_id=a.id AND
   r.time > 0
   r1.time < r2.time
 ORDER BY r.time
```

but that caused a out of memory error.  The results table has over a million entries and the athletes entry has over 15,000.  So the question remains, is there an efficient way of sorting the grouped records or should I have the PHP script remove results as the record set is looped.

Comment: What do you mean *...it's not sorting by the time correctly...*? Can you provide desired output based on your sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT q.athlete_id aid, a.first, a.last, r.id rid, q.`time`
  FROM
(SELECT athlete_id, MIN(`time`) `time`
  FROM results
 WHERE time > 0
 GROUP BY athlete_id) q JOIN results r
    ON q.athlete_id = r.athlete_id 
   AND q.`time` = r.`time` JOIN athletes a
    ON q.q.athlete_id = a.id
 ORDER BY q.`time`
```

Output:

```
| AID | FIRST |    LAST | RID | TIME |
--------------------------------------
|   1 |   Sam | Johnson |   1 | 1302 |
|   2 |  Adam |   Jones |   3 | 1491 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56ab5/1)**

Comment: Thanks peterm. I ended up doing something very similar to this.